# Choose two numbers proof

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are 25 Numbers $x_1<x_2<…<x_n$

Eg. (1,2,3…,23,24,25) or any arbitrary other series (1,30,99,302,405,…)

Prove that you can choose two numbers such that both the sum and the difference of these two numbers don’t equal one of the other numbers.

Its a riddle out of winklers book. I don‘t understand the solution.

The solution says: If $x_n$ is not one of the two numbers then for any $x_i$ smaller than $x_n$ there must be an $x_j$ such that $x_i + x_j = x_n$.

This leads to the 24 numbers being connected such that $x_i + x_{n-i-1} = x_n$.

(First confusion: Why would they be connected in such a weird way? $x_{n-1}$ is not even in there?)

Now all $x_{n-1} + x_i >= x_n$
. Therefore, $x_2…x_{n-2}$ must be pairs again for which this time $x_{n-1} = x_{2+i} + x_{n-i-2}$

(Second confusion: well ok, everything is bigger than $x_n$ ok, but what does that say? And why we just drop $x_2$ and only consider all above?)

So we see that $x_{n-1}$ and $x_{(n-1)/2}$ is a solution to the riddle.

I don‘t get any of the steps behind the solution. It makes 0 sense to me. To group the pairs in such s way.

Can anybody explain it to me in more detail? Or in an other way?

Comment: Would you be willing to edit your question with Mathjax? A guide to Mathjax can be found here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/1119495

Comment: Can you give a numerical example for this claim?

Comment: Editted. I can‘t think of any numerical example. It’s a proof out of a math competition in russia

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Say the numbers are $\{0, \cdots, 24\}$.  Can we just take $23, 24$ as the pair?  Sure the difference, $24-23=1$, is one of the other numbers but that will be true for any two you take.  The sum, $24+23=47$ is clearly not on the list, so is that good enough?  If $n=25$ in your post, then the official solution appears to be useless since $\frac {25-2}2$ isn't an integer.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  It isn't at all clear what $n$ is , for example.  If $n$ is meant to be $25$ then, as I remarked before, you can't look at $x_{(n-2)/2}$.

Comment: @Lulu. The problem is its not true for every pair like you stated. In your example it works as well -> the pair 12 and 24, because 24-12 = 12. so there is not any other number equaling this difference. And 24+12 also works of course. So the pair 24,12 fulfills the riddle.

Comment: I suggest editing your post to include this example.  I didn't understand that it was ok if the difference matched one of the two terms.  And I still don't understand what $n$ is in your post.  If $n=25$, then say that.  And explain what $\frac {n-2}2$ means in this case.

Comment: Thanks. I added the numerical and editted the typo

Comment: Note:  Your assumption on $x_{25}$ only makes sense if it reads "Assume that $x_{25}$ *can't* be one of the two numbers."  Under that assumption, then (since $x_{25}$ clearly isn't the difference of any two terms) it must be the case that, for each $j<n$ there is some $i$ with $x_i+x_j=x_{25}$ (exercise).  Of course, if that assumption is false, then we are already done.

Comment: @lulu That one is certain. But the following steps, I don‘t manage to understand.

Comment: Well, having corrected that in your post, the rest seems obvious, no?  Starting with $x_1$ there must be some $j$ with $x_1+x_j=x_{25}$ and that has to be $j=24$, else what would $x_{24}$ be paired with?

Comment: I dont know, I dont see the second part of the proof. Yes it means we find pairs such that they equal $x_{25}$, but how can we show for sure that this pair is not equal to one of the other numbers when we subtract them? E.g. 22 and 2 would be a pair but the difference is 20 so invalid for the solution

Comment: $x_i + x_{n-i-1} = x_n$ seems to be a mistake. It should be $x_i + x_{n-i} = x_n$.

Comment: Not following.  We know those pairs are invalid because their sum is in the collection.  Maybe their difference is in the collection, maybe not.

Comment: The question is asking to find $(x_i,x_j)$ such that neither their sum nor difference is equal to some *other* number in the collection. That is, equal to some number that isn't $x_i$ or $x_j$. In particular, this allows $(x_i, x_j)$ to be a solution if $x_j - x_i = x_i$. Another way to put this is that if every pair has either its sum or difference within the collection, then there must be one element that is twice another.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I'm not certain what your point is. Note that 1/ $(x_i, x_j)$ with $x_j - x_i = x_i$ need not be a solution if $x_i + x_j = x_k$, and 2/ So what if $x_j = 2x_i$?  $\quad$ Furthermore, note that $x_{24}$ need not be equal to $2 x_{12}$, but is the solution set that works for all cases.

Comment: @CalvinLin My point is that it's not immediately obvious that the difference is allowed to be part of the set as long as it's equal to $x_i$. And the statement is false without that case.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Hm, isn't it obvious from the phrasing "don't equal one of the other numbers"?  $\quad$ I agree that without that, it's false in the case where $x_i$ is an artithmetic progression. Interestingly, if $x_i$ isn't an AP, then the statement is still true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more detailed explanation.

$n$ is an odd integer.

1. Proof by contradiction. Suppose this is not possible.
2. What this means is that for every $i, j$, then $x_i + x_j$ or $x_i - x_j$ must equal to some other $x_k$ for $k\neq i, j$.  (This is the key observation which I wish they stated).
3. Consider $ i = n$. Since $x_n + x_j > x_n$, so it can't be equal to $x_k$. Thus, we must have $x_n - x_j = x_{k(j) }$ for all $j$.
4. This establishes a unique pairing of $x_j + x_{k(j) } = x_n$ for all $j$. We also have $x_{ k(j) } + x_{k(k(j))} = x_n$ so $ k(k(j))= j$. So, we have a bijection of the values from 1 to $n-1$.
5. We prove by induction that $k(j) = n-j$.

   - Consider $j=1$. Proof by contradiction. Suppose $k(1) \neq n-1$, so $k(1) < n-1$ and thus $x_1 + x_{k(1)} = x_n$. But then, $x_n = x_{n-1} + x_{k(n-1) } > x_{k(1) } + x_1 = x_n$. Thus $k(1) = n-1$.
   - Consider $j = 2$. Proof by contradiction. Suppose  $k(2) \neq n-2$, so (since $k(1) = n-1$ from above) $k(2) < n-2$ and thus $x_n = x_{n-2} + x_{k(n-2)}  > x_{k(2)} + x_2 = x_n$.  Thus $k(2) = n-2$.
   - Proceed by induction to show that $k(j) = n-j$.
6. Thus, we conclude that $x_j + x_{n-j} = x_n$.
7. Now, consider the $n-1$ numbers $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4 < \ldots < x_{n-1}$. Observe that for $j\geq 2$, $x_{n-1} + x_j > x_{n-1} + x_1  = x_n$, so we must have $x_{n-1} - x_j$ equal some other $x_{l(j)}$.

   - We will show that $l(n-2) = 1, l(n-3) = 2, \ldots, l(\frac{n-1}{2} +1 ) = \frac{n-1}{2} - 1 $.
   - Consider $j=n-2$. Since $x_{n-2} + x_2 = x_n$ from above, and $x_{n-2} + x_{l(n-2)} = x_{n-1} < x_n = x_{n-2} + x+2$, so $l(n-2) = 1$.
   - Consider $j = n-3$. Since $x_{n-3} + x_3 = x_n$ and $x_{n-2} + x_ 1 = x_{n-1}$, thus $x_{n-2} + x_1 = x_{n-1} = x_{n-3} + x_{l(n-3)} < x_n = x_{n-3} + x_3$ gives $ 1 < l(n-3) < 3$ so $l(n-3) = 2$ as desired.
   - Continue by induction.
8. Notice that $x_{n-1} - x_{\frac{n-1}{2} }$ is now the odd-one-out.

   - This is $> x_1$ since $x_{n-1} = x_{\frac{n-1}{2} + 1 } + x_{\frac{n-1}{2} - 1 } > x_{\frac{n-1}{2} } + x_1$.
   - It cannot equal any other $x_k$, for $k \neq 1, \frac{n-1}{2}$, since the other numbers are paired up.
9. Also, $ x_{n-1} + x_{\frac{n-1}{2} } > x_{n-1} + x_1 = x_n$.
10. Thus, the sum and difference of $x_{n-1} , x_{\frac{n-1}{2}}$ do not equal any other $x_k$ for $k \neq \frac{n-1}{2}, n-1$.

Notes

- We do not yet know if $x_{n-1} - x_{\frac{n-1}{2} } =  x_{\frac{n-1}{2} }$. In fact, this need not be the case as we'd see below.
- The sets that satisfy the structure we have found ($x_i + x_{n-1} = x_n, x_i + x_{n-1-i} = x_{n-1} $) are: For some constants $A$ and $I$, $x_i = iA$ for $i = 1$ to 12, $x_i = I + iA$ for $i = 13$ to $25$.
- From this, we can see that the only $(x_i, x_j)$ that work for all possible cases is $(x_{12}, x_{24})$.

  - For example, $(x_{11}, x_{22})$ doesn't work for $ A = 1, I = 1$, since $x_{11} = 11, x_{12} = 12, x_{22} = 23$ so $ x_{22} - x_{11} = x_{12}$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this very detailed description. 

What I still don’t see is: how did you know at point 8, to take exactly n-1 and (n-1)/2 as a pair?

Comment: @RickDänzer I didn't "know" for certain at that point in time. Considering those terms is motivated by the following: 1/ It was the odd-one-out, so it might produce the contradiction that we want 2/ The "counterexample" that we were trying to understand felt like an arithmetic progression, for which it's clear that $x_{24}, x_{12}$ satisfied the conditions. (Of course, there are other values, like $x_{22}, x{_11}$.)

Comment: Thanks again a lot! Sorry I‘m very new to all these pure math puzzles. So I probably need a bit more time and courage to just try things out, when I don’t „know“ it right away! Thanl you!

Comment: @RickDänzer Yes, heuristics like "trial and error", "try small cases", "wishful thinking" etc are very helpful to guide what to try, though it takes time and effort to see what could work.. $\quad$ Note that upon further review, I feel that point 7 has a gap in it, and I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: @RickDänzer See the edited note. I included all possible solutions to the structure that we found (the system of linear equations). From these, notice that $x_{24}, x_{12}$ is the only one that is guaranteed to work for all cases. This is another reason why we focus on $x_{n-1}, x_{(n-1)/2}$.